# "I never saw it before" vs. "I have never seen it before"

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Is there any difference in meaning between *I never saw it before* and *I have never seen it before* when talking about life expriences? For example:

> **I never saw** such a big fish in real life **before**. This is the first time.
>
> **I have never seen** such a big fish in real life **before**. This is the first time.

Until recently, I would have thought that the first sebtences was incorrect. But, in the 11th episode of the 10th season of *Friends*,  one of the characters used the Past Simple instead of the Present Perfect. Here it is:

> Roy: What's the matter? **You never saw** a 50 year old stripper cry
> **before**?

Would the meaning be exactly the same if he said *you have never seen a 50 year old stripper cry before*?

Comment: To my (British) ears _I never saw ... before_ sounds quintessentially American. The _before_ sets this in a period of time continuing up to the present, so I would always use the present perfect _I've never seen ... before_.

Answer (score 1):

To agree with Colin, as an American speaker, I'm pretty sure these are dialectical differences. I can hear native speakers saying either one.

Comment: American native, anyway  8>)  (from a fellow American)