# We've never seen a real dinosaur

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Dinosaurs were extinct long ago.

> We, the humans in the 21st century, have never seen a real dinosaur.

> We, the humans in the 21st century, never saw a real dinosaur.

Why is the second sentence correct and the first wrong? What's the logic behind it? Someone said when the last such opportunity has ended, we should use past tense. I can't figure out why.

past period, when dinosaurs lived >>>> 21st century, when we live

never: not at any time

Why does the past simple imply dinosaurs were extinct, and the present perfect imply they are still alive with us, which is impossible.

Comment: I would have said the opposite: the first sentence is correct and the second sentence is not.

Comment: Could you explain the reason please?

Comment: As a British English speaker I would use the first one. I suspect an American might use the second. (c.f. the Gelett Burgess verse _I never saw a purple cow_.) See also [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253784/i-never-saw-it-before-vs-i-have-never-seen-it-before?rq=1)

Comment: @KateBunting Our usage is similar to the British AFAIK. Most U.S. grammar instructors would object to that Burgess sentence.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Perhaps grammar instructors would object, but it was, in its day, a **very** popular verse, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_Cow I think most people would understand it as short for "*I never (yet) saw a  purple cow*". In any case I, for one, consider it perfectly good English. If one is to judge by usage, the popularity of "The Purple Cow" argues strongly for it.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Consider also : "*I never nurs’d a dear gazelle / To glad me with its soft black eye, / But when it came to know me well /  And love me, it was sure to die!*" by Thomas Moore https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44781/lalla-rookh

Comment: @David I’m certainly not saying that people don’t say such things (there are many, many more examples), but I suspect that the extent to which instructors consider it correct / incorrect is similar in the U.S. and Britain. I don’t have any hard data, though.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I have no data on what instructors consider correct on this issue in either the US or the UK, nor the relative percentage who consider it wrong. I am saying that it is quite irrelevant. Respected writers and people in general have used the form "I never {verbed} an {adjective} {noun}" and that construction is thus proper, views on any instructors notwithstanding. Instructors do not define correct English.

Comment: The *never [past tense verb]* construct is used often in AmE to mean *didn't [present tense verb]*.   So you have people saying *never saw* instead of *didn't see*.  Usually this is just a vernacular usage and is frowned upon by the scholarly club.  However, *never [verbed]* is also commonly used to negate an expectation.  For example, you went to Dinosaur World Adventure Park (which promises real dinosaurs) but while there you saw no dinosaurs.  This will very often be reported as, *I went to Dinosaur World but **never** saw one.*

Comment: This has ZERO to do with British or American English. It has to do with **meaning**.  I never go to the beach AND I have never been to the beach. The PP just tells us it is past in relation to the present **at the time of speaking**. I have never answered a question here without a lot of brouhaha. :) [I am still answering questions. and in the OP's sentence, people are continuing to see into the present regardless of what they may or may not have seen].

Answer (score 1):

People in the 20th century *didn't see* a real dinosaur, because the 20th century is complete and not seeing a dinosaur is complete. People in the 21st  century *haven't seen* a dinosaur because the 21st century is not complete. The fact that dinosaurs are extinct is irrelevant. Sometime later in the 21st century, someone might invent a time machine, go back millions of years and bring a real dinosaur back.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with [the answer by user Sydney](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/307509/91457). It is my view that both of:

> - (1) We, the humans in the 21st century, have never seen a live dinosaur.

> - (2) We, the humans in the 21st century, never saw a live dinosaur.

are perfectly valid English sentences.

(To be slightly pedantic, I and many other humans now alive, have seen a real dinosaur, albeit not a live one. Dinosaur skeletons are "real" dinosaurs, although long dead. But this is not relevant to the grammatical point.)

(2) could be taken as short for "... never (yet) saw ..."

If one  considers

> (2a) The humans in the 20th century never saw a live dinosaur.

it says that, the 20th century being over, no human during that period saw a live dinosaur.

Now for the distinctions:

(1) with its use of the present perfect, implies that the action of "not seeing a live dinosaur" started in thje past, and continues up to the present.

(2) with it use of the simple past, implies that the action of not seeing a live dinosaur took place in the past.  That might be taken to mean that this is complete and can never occur. But in theory someone might somehow see a live dinosaur sometime after 2022 (although this is quite unlikely). This (2) will be taken as short for

> (2B) We, the humans in the 21st century, never **yet** saw a live dinosaur.

that also implies that the act of not seeing a live dinosaur occurred in the past and continues through the present. In short the actual meaning is much the same, the difference is one of style and emphasis. I think (2) is a bit more likely to be said by a native speaker, although I personally might prefer (1). But either is acceptable and the meaning conveyed is much the same.

Comment: To be even more pedantic, modern birds are phylogenetically dinosaurs.

Answer (score 0):

One use of the perfect is to emphasize that something has (or has not) ever happened. This is called the *existential perfect*. For example:

- Have you read *Catch-22*?
- No, I've never read it. / I haven't ever read it. / I haven't read it before.

The simple past might be a bit odd in these situations because it suggests you are talking about a particular time in the past. The sentence

- Did you read *Catch-22*?

is perfectly grammatical, but suggests a narrower slice of time under discussion. For example, if the addressee was given a choice of books to read, it would be a way to ask whether the one they chose was *Catch-22*.

If a particular time period in the past is specified, the perfect may be inappropriate:

- ?Have you read *Catch-22* as a child?

sounds odd. "Did you (ever) read *Catch-22* as a child?" is better, because it is about a particular period of time.

In some dialects, "ever" and "never" can be used with the simple past even without implying a particular time period. Examples include the folk song ["Did You Ever See a Lassie?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Did_You_Ever_See_a_Lassie%3F) and the expression "I never met a ___ I didn't like" ([explanation here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/490379/what-is-the-meaning-of-youve-never-met-a-graph-you-didnt-like)). To me (AmE speaker) this sounds colloquial: in formal writing I would prefer the perfect for such sentences.